# Adjust placement of table in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I'm looking to move the placement of one of the tables in this app all the way to the left (below the sidebar panel)

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput("file", "Upload CSV File"),
      selectInput("batter", "Select Batter", choices = NULL),
      selectInput("graphType", "Select Graph Type", choices = c("Ranking", "Spray Chart", "Strike Zone"))
    ),
    mainPanel(
      conditionalPanel(
        condition = "input.graphType == 'Ranking'",
        plotOutput("p1", height = 250),
        plotOutput("p2", height = 250),
        plotOutput("p3", height = 250),
        plotOutput("p4", height = 250)
      ),
      conditionalPanel(
        condition = "input.graphType == 'Spray Chart'",
        girafeOutput("p5"),
        tableOutput("p9")
      ),
      conditionalPanel(
        condition = "input.graphType == 'Strike Zone'",
        girafeOutput("p6"),
        girafeOutput("p7"),
        girafeOutput("p8")
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  data <- reactive({
    req(input$file)
    read.csv(input$file$datapath, header = TRUE, sep = ",")
  })
  
  observe({
    updateSelectInput(
      inputId = "batter",
      choices = unique(data()$Batter)
    )
  })
```

```
  output$p9 <-renderTable({
    req(input$batter)
    
    p <- data() %>%
      filter(Batter == input$batter, PitchCall == "InPlay") %>% 
      select(Date, Batter, PitcherThrows, TaggedPitchType, ExitSpeed, Angle, Distance, HangTime)
    
    p
  })
```

[This is what it currently looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IrNbN.png)

I'm trying to move the table all the way to the left so all the data is in view but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Put `tableOutput("p9")` in `sidebarPanel` like this: `sidebarPanel(
      fileInput("file", "Upload CSV File"),
      selectInput("batter", "Select Batter", choices = NULL),
      selectInput("graphType", "Select Graph Type", choices = c("Ranking", "Spray Chart", "Strike Zone")),
      tableOutput("p9")
    ),`

Comment: Theres too much data in the table for it to fit properly in the sidebarPanel and I only want it visible when the "spray chart" is selected. Im trying to keep it the way it is, just moved all the way to the left.

Comment: If you want to put something below the sidebar panel, I think you have to make your  own sidebar panel with `wellPanel`.

Comment: Any suggestions on how to do that or where I could find that information?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way:

```r
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

mySidebarLayout <- function(
    sidebar,
    belowSidebar,
    mainPanel
){
  fluidRow(
    column(
      width = 4,
      wellPanel(
        sidebar
      ),
      belowSidebar
    ),
    column(
      width = 8,
      mainPanel
    )
  )
}

mysidebar <- function(...) {
  list(...)
}

myBelowSidebar <- function(...) {
  list(...)
}

myMainPanel <- function(...) {
  list(...)
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  mySidebarLayout(
    sidebar = mysidebar(
      fileInput("file", "Upload CSV File"),
      selectInput("batter", "Select Batter", choices = NULL),
      selectInput("graphType", "Select Graph Type", choices = c("Ranking", "Spray Chart", "Strike Zone"))
    ),
    
    belowSidebar = myBelowSidebar(
      tableOutput("mytable")
    ),
    
    mainPanel = myMainPanel(
      plotOutput("gg")
    )
    
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output[["mytable"]] <- renderTable({
    iris[c(1:2, 51:52, 101:102), ]
  })
  output[["gg"]] <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(iris[c(1:2, 51:52, 101:102), ]) + 
      geom_point(aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]